# refactoring date and time columns convertion to Time(WithZone)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I got 2 colums representing a date and a time.

`{dateproc: '2012-03-23', horproc: '2000-01-01 16:15:23 UTC'}`

Both are read as a TimeWithZone by rails. I need to combine them.

This is what I've done. It works, but it doesn't *feel* elegant, and it just doesn't seem readable.

```
date_time_combined = dateproc + horproc.seconds_since_midnight.seconds
```

Any advice improoving it?

Comment: You might try posting this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/